# Change on the back-end takes 30 mins or longer to show on front-end, what could possible be the cause?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am an experienced Joomla user but I've never seen something like this during my 4 years' Joomla life.
After I change anything on the back end, such as article's title, or menu item's title, the changes won't immediately show up on the front-end until about 30 minutes later. For some of my computers/browsers it changes a day after, and some hasn't changed at all yet even though I made the change 2 days ago.

At first I thought this was a problem of cache, but I've done clearing cache for browser and back-end, I even use some machine/browser that has never opened the page, the problem is still there. Besides I don't think things like menu item title or article title get into cache. So what could possibly be the cause of problem?

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare or a host with some super caching like SiteGround?

Comment: I am using dreamhost

Answer (score 2):

We have worked on a website with the exact same problem this morning - and it turned out that they were using an Amazon AWS reseller who really maxed up the server cache. The website had many issues because of "overcaching", and the problem was that there was no setting whatsoever to override the cache in that particular scenario.

I suggest you take it to your host and discuss it with them.

Note: As the first comment on your question mentioned, SiteGround is one of those hosts where this problem is very common.

Comment: itoctopus hit the nail on the head.

Comment: I am hosted with dreamhost. I contact their customer support they gave me a url with proxy, where I can see the changes I make immediately. Then they told me this means the contents are correctly served by them. I am being more confused.. moreover, after I brought up this issue, they said they would clear the "server cache". After the clearing, I did notice that my site took much longer to load. But clearing cache doesn't help with the issue, I still can't see changes immediately

Comment: There are many types ("type" might not be the right word here, but I can't find a different word to describe it) of caching - they might have disabled one, but left others. We just worked on a host with 3 types of caching - it was only until the host disabled the last caching type that we saw the changes (the host insisted it wasn't their fault until they disabled the last type of caching). Shared hosts are using increasingly aggressive caching methods so that they can cram even more websites on the same server (without crashing it).